# Multiple column layout with collection view compositional layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am converting some hairy collection view code (scroll views with embedded stack views, collection views, table views, etc.) to a single collection view with compositional layout. But I am having troubles with “two column” layout when using the `count` parameter.

To experiment, I downloaded Apple’s [Implementing Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) sample, looked at the [Create a Column Layout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views#4208521) code, which has this example:

```swift
extension TwoColumnViewController {
    /// - Tag: TwoColumn
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                              heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                               heightDimension: .absolute(44))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 2)
        let spacing = CGFloat(10)
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }
}
```

In their demo app, you get there by navigating to “Compositional Layout” » “Getting Started” » “Two-Column Grid”. Anyway, this yields:

[image]

OK, that’s fine.

But in iOS 16, `horizontal(layoutSize:subitem:count:)` is deprecated:

[image]

And if you replace it with `horizontal(layoutSize:repeatingSubitem:count:)`, you get a layout like the following (where you cannot even scroll to the right to see the cells offscreen):

[image]

How do you get columnar output in iOS 16 and later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `horizontal(layoutSize:subitem:count:)`, with `horizontal(layoutSize:repeatingSubitem:count:)` you have to adjust the width of the item or group. E.g.:

```swift
extension TwoColumnViewController {
    /// - Tag: TwoColumn
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5),  // NB: 0.5, not 1.0
                                              heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                                               heightDimension: .absolute(44))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, repeatingSubitem: item, count: 2)
        let spacing = CGFloat(10)
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }
}
```

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutgroup/3975795-horizontal) for the new method says:

> It’s your responsibility to ensure that the group’s `layoutSize` can fit `count` repetitions of this item.

I find that I can either adjust the `widthDimension` of the `NSCollectionLayoutItem` of the item or the group to `.fractionalWidth(0.5)`, and it renders the two-column collection view.

I hope the above helps someone else save a little time when working through Apple’s [compositional layout examples](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views).